# local base of subspace

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a normal space,
If we have a countable local base at the point m in the remainder of Stone -cech
compactification $\beta X\setminus X$, can we say the point m has also a countable
local base in $\beta X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The Čech-Stone compactification of $\omega_1$ is $\omega_1+1$, its one-point compactification, so the remainder is a singleton, $\{\omega_1\}$. However, the character of the point $\omega_1$ in $\omega_1+1$ is $\omega_1$; it does not have a countable local base. The space $\omega_1$ has the topology induced by a linear order, so it is normal.

Comment: @ege: You’re welcome.